# unmatched records from two tables having common columns

Tags: sql, full-outer-join

```
t1

1  ajay
2  ravi
3  gaurav
5  naveen
7  sachin

t2

1  ajay
2  ravi
4  alok
6  raja
```

I need unmatched rows

```
3
5
7
4
6
```

My Query

```
select * from t1 A
full outer join t2 B
on A.id=B.id

where not exists(select A.name intersect B.name);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need filtration with `coalesce()` :

```
select coalesce(t.id, t1.id) as unmatched_ids
from t full outer join
     t1
     on t1.id = t.id
where (t.id is null or t1.id is null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Good day, please try the below code.

Note eg of [Name] = ajay, ravi,raja

```
SELECT A.*,
B.*
from t1 [A]
FULL JOIN t2 [B]
WHERE A.id=B.id
AND A.[Name]<>B.[Name]
```

Hope this helps, Thank you